# What events does an Azure Windows VM receive during a planned maintenance shutdown?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When Azure shuts down a VM for planned maintenance, what messages do running services see, if any?

For example, do they get a ServiceBase.OnShutdown() message and, if so, how long does the service / server get to complete shutdown processing?

Does MS give any extra leeway to its own apps? E.g. if a VM is running SQL Server, will Azure wait for SQL Server to stop cleanly before shutting down the VM?

[I can't find this in the documentation and, unfortunately, I don't have the access or the programming skills to try it out for myself.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what messages do running services see, if any?

Based on my knowledge, for now, Azure does not support this. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/4904334-provide-maintenance-notifications).

Typically maintenance is performed at weekends for VMs not in an availability set to minimize impact on services. Normally notification is given 7 days in advance with the minimum being 3 business days. A start time for the maintenance is given with the expected duration. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-planned-maintenance#email-notification).

According to your description, I suggest you could provision another IaaS VM with your SQL server and put in the same [Availability set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-planned-maintenance#multi-instance-configuration-updates). By doing this, Azure will ensure that both your VMs do not go down simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Walter, that feedback comment was useful  (and I would never have found it myself). So my conclusion is that machines just die - as if the power had been pulled. If anyone knows any different, feel free to add.